# How to create a model in DRY pattern with help of flow.js (for async calls) in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns, redis

For example,

```
function user(){
    flow.exec(
        function(){
            call a; 
        },
        function(){
            call b;
        }
    );
}

function posts(){
    flow.exec(
        function(){
            call a; 
        },
        function(){
            call c;
        }
    );
}
```

as per above code, How can i make a call to common functions(call a) on different models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function perform(first, second) {
  flow.exec(first, second);
}

function callA() {
  a();
}

function callB() {
  b();
}

perform(callA, callB);
```